# how can we use delete http request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

when i try to delete data by this code its not working

```
router.delete('/delete-screen/:id',(req,res)=>{
  let proId=req.params.id
  console.log(proId)
  theaterHelpers.deleteOwner(proId).then((response)=>{
    res.redirect('/theater/screens')
  })
})
```

but using this code it working

```
router.get('/delete-screen/:id',(req,res)=>{
  let proId=req.params.id
  console.log(proId)
  theaterHelpers.deleteOwner(proId).then((response)=>{
    res.redirect('/theater/screens')
  })
})
```

**what i done is replace delete  to get, My question is how can make a http delete request in my code**

my delete function code is

```
deleteScreen:(screenId)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        db.get().collection(collection.SCREEN_COLLECTION).removeOne({_id:ObjectID(screenId)}).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            resolve(response)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: It's not working in what sense? Btw, your examples are calling deleteOwner not deleteScreen

Comment: means when i using router.delete its not working

Comment: Right, but what is happening (or not happening) that makes you conclude it's not working?

Comment: i want to http delete method to delete the data

Comment: Can you show how you are making the request to `/delete-screen/:id`? is it a http form or some JS library call?

Comment: here i am not using any http delete method right how can i use here

Comment: look here it is http get request

Comment: by get request taking the id of the data to delete and using remove method i deleting the data

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a server-rendered application, then you can only issue GET and POST requests. The only way to trigger a delete route handler is to trick your application into thinking the incoming request actually has DELETE semantics. You can do this by modifying the `request.method` property before the request is actually handed to the router.

There are a number of ways to achieve this, and the `method-override` package has got you covered.

For instance, the following setup would update `request.property` for incoming GET requests to the value provided with the `_method` query parameter.

```
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
app.use(methodOverride("_method", { methods: ["GET"] }))
```

Then, accordingly add a `_method` query parameter with the DELETE value to the url you want to use to trigger you delete route handler.

```
yourUrl?_method=DELETE
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override